# union of bounded subsets bounded

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:**

Show that a finite union of bounded sets is again bounded.

**Proof:**

Suppose $A, B$ are subsets in metric space $(M,d)$, and $\alpha$, $\beta$ are upper bounds for $A,B$ respectivly.

WLOG, let $\alpha \geq \beta$. Then $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $A\cup B$, because $\forall x >\alpha$, $$x>\alpha \Longrightarrow x>\beta \Longrightarrow x \notin A \wedge x\notin B \Longrightarrow x\notin A\cup B$$

Is my proof valid? Feels to me like its missing something.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is not used after its definition.

Comment: Thanks, I changed $\epsilon$ to $x$

Comment: What do you mean by "upper bound" of a subset of a metric space? And by "$x>\alpha$" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine if your metric space is the real line. In general recall that a set in a metric space is called bounded if it is  a subset of some open ball. Suppose $A \subset B(x,r)$ and $B \subset B(y,s)$. Verify (using triangle inequality)  that $A\cup B \subset B(x,r+s+d(x,y))$ and conclude that $A \cup B$ is bounded.

Comment: To extend to a union of multiple bounded sets,A_1,...,A_n, can I just say that since $A_1\cup A_2=B_1,$ and $B_1$ is bounded, this implies that $ B_1\cup A_3$ is also bounded?

Comment: Yes, once you prove that union of two bounded sets is bounded you can conclude, by induction, that the union of any finite number of bounded sets is bounded.